# Meteor js can't create new user

Tags: javascript, meteor

I get this error when I try to create a new meteor user:

[image]

I only updated meteor and didn't touch any validation functions,

Does anybody know why the validation doesn't allow me to create a user with more than **3** characters? How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried removing and adding the accounts packages again?

Comment: yes, I removed all the accounts packages and reinstalled them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked into the current code of the [accounts-unstyled package](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/accounts-ui-unstyled/login_buttons.js). Line 87 states:

```
validateUsername = function (username) {
  if (username.length >= 3) {
    return true;
  } else {
    loginButtonsSession.errorMessage("Username must be at least 3 characters long");
    return false;
  }
};
```

The last time this file was changed was 7 months ago.

**Conclusion:**

The problem doesn't lie in the meteor code. Are you using meteorite? What's the meteor version that you updated to? Maybe the problem lies somewehere there. Unfortunately I can't tell you anything more detailed at the moment as I don't have access to my own meteor environment right now.

**Possible solution:**

Create a new and clean meteor project, add all the required packages and copy your code over to the new directory. Hopefully it works then at that point.

Comment: I created a test meteor app, added accounts-base accounts-ui and accounts-password and was able to create an account with username 123